# Properties of $X′(t)=AX(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

I am studying some properties of the initial value problem
\begin{equation*}
   \begin{cases}
 \frac{d}{dt}X(t)=A(t)X(t),\\
  X(t_0)=I.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
where $A(t)$ is a real-valued $n\times n$ matrix.

If we denote as $X(t,t_0)$ the solution of this problems, we have the following properties:

- $X(t,r)=X(t,s)X(s,r)$
- $X(s,t)=X(t,s)^{-1}$

I want to show this two properties and I know how to proof the first one using the second. Basicly, if you define $Y(t)=X(t,s)X(s,r)$, you can do the following calculation:

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        \frac{d}{dt}Y(t)&=\frac{d}{dt}X(t,s)X(s,r)
        \\
        &=A(t)X(t,s)X(s,r)
        \\
        &=A(t)Y(t).
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}

It is also easy to see that $Y(r)=I$ using the second property and we have the first property. My problem is, how can I prove the second property?

Comment: Have you tried to use the chain rule? Take the derivative of both sides and show that they match. Then look at $s=t$ and use Picard (if A(t) is good enough).

Comment: I tried applying the chain rule and got that $\frac{d}{dt}X^{-1}(t,s)=-X^{-1}(t,s)\frac{d}{dt}X(t,s)X^{-1}(t,s)=-X^{-1}(t,s)A(t)$. So if I define $Y(t)=X^{-1}(t,s)$, i get that $\frac{d}{dt}Y(t)=-Y(t)A(t)$ and I can't continue because I don't know how to commute A and Y.

Comment: But if $X(t,s)\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $n>1$, then we can't even define $X(t,s)^{-1}$, so, I assume that, for this case, $X(t,s)\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Here X and A are $n\times n$ matrices and you can assume that $X(t,s)^{-1}$ is invertible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can show these properties by allowing the both the time and value in the intial conditions to vary. Define $X(t,r,B)$ as solution to the initial value problem
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{d}{dt}X(t,r,B)=A(t)X(t,r,B) \\
X(r,r,B)=B
\end{cases}$$
Since $\frac{d}{dt}(X(t,r,I)B)=\frac{d}{dt}(X(t,r,I))B$, we see by right multiplying the entire IVP by $B$ that $X(t,r,B)=X(t,r,I)B$. Now, by *assuming* solutions exist for all time and are unique, any solutions that agree at one time agree everywhere. This implies
$$
X(t,r,I)=X(t,s,X(s,r,I))
$$
Applying the multiplicative property $X(t,r,B)=X(t,r,I)B$ gives the first property
$$
X(t,r,I)=X(t,s,I)X(s,r,I)
$$
The second property follows immediately from the first, since $X(t,s,I)X(s,t,I)=X(t,t,I)=I$.

Comment: Very clean proof. Thank you for the answer!